# What are the benefits of using multiple method tokens for ajax?

Tags: javascript, php, backbone.js

instead of doing all your server operations via the POST method token ( and the content type set to json ).

I've done some research here and I am referring to the method tokens mentioned in the ietf document.

https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-5.1.1

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest

I don't see the benefit of using all the other server type requests.  I know they are used, particularly what spurned this interest was Backbone's use as seen here:

```
var methodMap = {
    'create': 'POST',
    'update': 'PUT',
    'patch':  'PATCH',
    'delete': 'DELETE',
    'read':   'GET'
  };
```

These properties are eventually passed to the xhr open method which you can read about in the links I posted above.

Actually the MDN article has pretty much no information while the W3 articles seems a bit esoteric.

Comment: its called REST. there are a ton of resources that explain the philosophy.

Comment: What you've described is not CRUD. It's REST. CRUD is simply a label for applications that stores data in a database. It can be simple POST/GET app, REST, old-school form submission, Excel Spreadsheet with macros etc.

Comment: Part of the reason CRUD is called CRUD is because it has double meaning - the acronym stands for Create/Read/Update/Delete which are the basic operations on data and also the word "crud" means disgusting. Developers don't like developing CRUD apps because it's boring. It's basically just wrapping a GUI (usually forms) around SQL queries - nothing creative.

Comment: Question updated, I don't care about CRUD or REST, the question is more practical, should I put the time in to use other `method tokens` as defined in the ietf document I linked to.  Currently I only use post and my app works fine.

Comment: At the end of the day, it's just a website, right? Why complicate that which you've already achieved? If you're looking for security, then that's a whole other discussion. But I see people needlessly complicate stuff allll ddaaayyy llloonnggg when, as I said, at the end of the day, you're just sending stuff to/from the server. Sometimes thinking about that for a second helps you decide.

Comment: Though to elaborate, if you want your requests to be "semantic" in that your code is more organized, then it's not a horrible idea. When I code requests I DO distinguish between get/post. All the others seem a bit over the top to me - I say let those semantics be handled by the back-end application where that kind of logic belongs. Your front-end should just say "here, take this crap". It shouldn't be concerned with what/how/why all of that happens. But that's just my 2 cents as a full-stack developer.

Comment: I agree, but I'm porting to Backbone, and Backbone internally calls these method types - GET,POST,PUT, and DELETE and if you pass the option in it will use PATCH.  I'm OK with using only POST and believe it is the most secure, I just need to find a way re-write `Backbone.sync` to work only with POST.

Comment: @dude - Besides I don't feel the complexity of server interactions can be boiled down to CRUD on the client.  What about the simple case of a  new user.  You do a CREATE but than you also GET some values in one operation.  There are other cases where I create data and get data in one round trip ajax call.

Answer (score 2):

What you've described is an application design philosophy called Representational State Transfer (REST). The philosophy is much more encompassing than just using multiple request methods. It also covers the idea that each type of data needs its own URL, how that URL should be logically structured and what should belong to query parameters and what should be a URL path. REST is one of the earliest ideas related to Semantic Web - the idea that websites should be easily readable to machines as it is to humans (or to put it another way, the idea that the website should be easily understandable to developers as it is to regular users).

You can read the original paper describing REST here: http://www.ics.uci.edu/~fielding/pubs/dissertation/rest_arch_style.htm

REST is actually just one chapter in the whole paper. The paper describes what a web architecture should ideally look like.

### Do you need REST?

The short answer is of course no. Technically speaking you're allowed to do whatever you want that works. Indeed, back when ideas of REST was first introduced there were no easy way to do PUT and DELETE requests on some browsers. So people stuck to GET and POST and the HTTP spec was updated specifically to make GET and POST have RESTful meaning.

The HTTP specification **recommends** that GET only be used for indempotent operations (requests with no side effect) while POST should be used whenever a request causes something to change in the server. But developers have been using GET to update databases due to easy debugging because you can just construct the query in the URL entry field in your browser. The RESTful way is to only allow POST requests to update the database (or save anything to file).

### What's the advantage?

The advantage is to essentially allow developers to treat the web as an API. Allowing machines to read webpages allows for things like mashups, creating mobile apps as front-ends etc.

A good API or library is consistent. A consistent API is easier to use, easier to remember and doesn't require the developer to look-up documentation too often. REST attempts to provide this consistency by giving real meaning to the types of request. Therefore if you see PUT request you don't have to guess what it's doing.

As such, as a programmer, it is to your advantage to not only be RESTful as much as possible but also convince as many other programmers as possible to create RESTful websites. If all websites are RESTful, writing scripts to do smart things with online data becomes much easier.

On the other hand, as a programmer, you also have the freedom to disagree with other people's ideas.

Comment: To be honest, I myself am one of those developers who tend to use GET for everything because it's easier to debug with a web browser. Though I do often implement the other ideas of REST such as having dedicated URLs for different types of data - usually done with Apache/lighttpd rewrite magic.

Comment: Very well said. The issue that I mentioned above is that while it's easy to write into a paper on the REST idea or a comment on stack overflow, in practice its often more complicated to classify what type of request should be used. Particularly, as you stated, for back-compat issues it's often not worth the business cost/developer sanity loss to implement ALL of these request types. Cheers to a good post, sir! +1!